# Power Automate Document Approval workflow for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZeJB4dGCq0) to make a flow for my document approval in SharePoint. my approval status, email doesn't work and whether I approve or reject the file, it still shows as 'Pending" in my SharePoint library.

I would appreciate your help to sort this out. (Screen shots are added)
Thanks,
Nastaran

[Power Automate Document Approval workflow for SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWjZK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have selected the correct file address(When an item or a file is modefied).
It may be that the file address of the trigger condition is wrongly selected, resulting in the email not being triggered.